# R - How to improve simpleCap to handle more complex names?

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching, capitalization, capitalize

I use a common function called `simpleCap` to properly format names in my database for reporting purposes:

```
simpleCap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}
```

Then, following another Stackoverflow post, I append `tolower()` to the beginning of this, to handle names entered in ALL CAPS:

```
simpleCap <- function(x) {
  x <- tolower(x)
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}
```

This works fine for names like "Greg Smith" or "Bob Jones", but I have Big Data containing a lot of more complex names. I could use some help addressing the following cases:

- the names "bin", "ibn", "de", and "del" should not be capitalized, e.g. "Sakib bin Salam"
- capitalization should apply to both names in a hyphenated name, e.g. "Peng-Jones"
- only the first letter in a name containing a single quote should be capitalized, e.g. "Ta'if" **UNLESS** the first letter is an "O" and the single quote is in the 2nd position like "O'Neil"
- Surnames beginning with "al-" or "as-" should only be capitalized after the hyphen
- Surnames beginning with "De" but with no space between "De" and the remaining last name should be capitalized like "DeGuest"
- Names with "Mac" (i.e. "MacDonald") should have the 1st and 4th letters capitalized
- Perhaps some other rule(s) that you may know of which I have not thought of

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

```
> "ADEDAYO  DAIBO"
> "EQEREM   ZEKA"
> "Mangaliso    Ndlovu"
> "Akamanwam    Itang"
> "Mohammed Al-Zahrani"
> "David    Fernando"
> "Adham    Obeidat"
> "TA'IF    Faithfull"
> "Bahaa    ALHAMMOUD"
> "Fatima   AlAli"
> "Tiffany  Scatliffe"
> "Imad Hameedullah"
> "HEIN ELLIS"
> "Victoria Francis-Anyanwu"
> "Michael  DeCesare"
> "chris    oboh"
> "La-Keisha    Wilmott"
> "sahar    al"
> "Yuri DEGUEST"
> "jim macdonald"
> "molly oneil"
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
> "Adedayo  Daibo"
> "Eqerem   Zeka"
> "Mangaliso    Ndlovu"
> "Akamanwam    Itang"
> "Mohammed al-Zahrani"
> "David    Fernando"
> "Adham    Obeidat"
> "Ta'if    Faithfull"
> "Bahaa    al-Hammoud"
> "Fatima   al-Ali"
> "Tiffany  Scatliffe"
> "Imad Hameedullah"
> "Hein Ellis"
> "Victoria Francis-Anyanwu"
> "Michael  DeCesare"
> "Chris    Oboh"
> "La-Keisha    Wilmott"
> "Sahar    Al"
> "Yuri DeGuest"
> "Jim MacDonald"
> "Molly O'Neil"
```

Comment: To improve your question, you should give sample input and desired output which can be used as a test case for all your rules. We can then assume any code that passes the test case is "correct" otherwise it's impossible to consider every possible international capitalization rule.

Comment: You changed "BahaaAlDean  ALHAMMOUD" to ""Bahaa-al-Dean    al-Hammoud" but did not specify any rules to add hyphens. If you don't provide a rule for this, it's difficult to program something.

Comment: @MrFlick True. I really don't know what the rule should be. I'm just going to change the example (though that was a real case from my data) because if we could just fix the other stuff then I can manually changes cases like that, or at least we'd still have made major progress. I suppose that as a human I know that it should be hyphenated because it "looks Middle Eastern" and contains "al", but I wouldn't know how to translate that to R short of using `tm` and/or `randomForest`.

Comment: How is your data structured? A data frame with 2 columns?

Comment: A data frame with many columns, though if it's easier I could make it just the 2 columns in question.

Comment: I think you might also get names like MacDonald and O'Neil which could complicate things further.

Comment: @JohnPaul you're absolutely correct! I will try to add that during my lunch break. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnPaul OK, I went ahead and added it.

Comment: Oy vey. This was me a year and a 20 months ago? Someone should've smacked me for not using `dput`